# Cannot import twitter4j classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter4j

I added twitter4j 3.0.3, into an Eclipse project but it does not import any classes from the jar. I copied in some code samples from the twitter4j jar files but eclipse can't find any of the classes in those files - e.g. `Twitter`, `ConfigurationBuilder`, `TwitterFactory` etc... I've added `twitter4j-core-3.0.3-sources.jar` to my build path. But Eclipse doesn't suggest to import any classes in these files. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar` JAR to your build path, it can be found under the `lib` directory of the download.

The `twitter4j-core-3.0.3-sources.jar` JAR only contains source code.