# How do I import twitter4j into eclipse?

Tags: android, twitter4j

I have downloaded *twitter4j-4.0.1.zip* from the [twitter4j page](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) and from [github](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/) in eclipse I unzip then file>import>Existing Android Code Into Workspace>next>browse file location, and eclipse does not find any projects. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338558/cannot-import-twitter4j-classes-in-eclipse) says to copy the jar file into the lib folder, but am I supposed to import as a library first? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried [this?](https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample). This is a android sample project.

Comment: no need to import LIB Project just put JAR file in LIB folder its enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338558/cannot-import-twitter4j-classes-in-eclipse) was correct. Right click your project>Properties>Java Build Path>Add External JARS>twitter4j-core

Comment: I have a query. Can we discuss at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50550/discussion-between-suhail-and-you